# Microsoft Access SQL select date after a certain date

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following is my SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM ClinicSession
WHERE ClinicDate > '01/11/2007'
AND NurseNo = 'N056';
```

Every time I click run I get data type mismatch in criteria expression.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, the date delimiter is hash (#). You should generally enter dates as #yyyy/mm/dd# Dates may get reformatted, depending on your interface and locale.

Comment: I did as you said and adding the # this allows the query to run but doesn't actually select the dates after 01/11/2007 but it does select all the fields with NurseNo N056

Comment: You used `WHERE ClinicDate > #2007/11/01#` ?

Comment: Ah the problem was I didn't use "year month day" as you suggested. I used "day month year". Thank you sir for your answer, all working now! :)